# Searching an old horror detective game

Tags: identify-this-game

There was a game that I played back in the 90's about a detective who was trying to solve a murder in a hotel. The scene kept changing from a normal hotel to a dilapidated horror one (not unlike the upside down from Stranger Things). It was an old point and click games, with buttons on the bottom (walk, look, use, etc). I remember that the bad things that happened in this game is connected to an old evil gaelic god or something... because its sacred tree was cut or something.

Can someone help me with the title?

Comment: I don't want to be rude to a newcomer, but I'm afraid to say that vague memories about having played a game seem to have little to do with actual retrocomputing.

Comment: Can you add some details? What kind of computer was the game on: Windows? Amiga? Nintendo 64? Something else?

Comment: @another-dave: But that's exactly what the [identify-this-game tag](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-game/info) is for, isn't it? The question needs more informations, but the 90s count as "retro".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6):

The game you're describing sounds like **Dark Seed**.

https://www.mobygames.com/game/302/dark-seed/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Seed_(video_game)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Having looked at the wikipedia link, I think there's enough to help the questioner here.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably pushing the boundaries of "retro," as the one I'm thinking of is from 2006, but it's in a retro style reminiscent of Sierra text-parser games. (It's built in Adventure Game Studio.) But since the question is still open, I'll answer this.

"Trilby's Notes" (2006) by Ben "Yahtzee" Croshaw fits this description. The main character is a gentleman cat-burglar-turned-detective. His case takes him to this hotel, and there are different tasks to perform in both the "proper" and the "horror" version of the hotel.

Unlike your recollection, it's built in the style of Sierra parser-based adventures, with a command line.

A Let's Play of the game is here: [TRILBY'S NOTES Adventure Game Gameplay Walkthrough - No Commentary Playthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g54NRoheDU) and the game itself is available from [Trilby's notes](http://www.fullyramblomatic.com/notes/).

Trilby is trying to trace an idol that kills people. It had been carved from a sacred tree; it contains the soul of a pain elemental.

Comment: The "sacred tree" part sounds promising, seeing as the OP mentioned that, and it wasn't addressed in the "Dark Seed" answer.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much.